# Reopen the app after certain period

Tags: objective-c, xcode, multitasking

I have an app A and app B. The app A is a manage or monitor tool to open app B to do certain Job, but sometimes the app B will crash unexpectedly.

1) Is that any ways i could tell app A, the app B has crashed and reopen the app B?
2) If there is no ways to tell app A, is that timeout will help app A to reopen app B?

I have tried to reopen app B, but the app A since like stay in background thread and unable to perform any action.
Because i do not know what is the better keyword to help me search case as i mentioned above.

Comment: Which method do you used in app A to open app B?

Comment: [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];